# tinymce won't get (id) or setcontent

Tags: tinymce, textarea

Here is my code that I'm using. I'm trying to get tinymce to load existing data into the TEXTAREA, but nothing I've tried so for, nor any "solutions" I've so far located have worked. The editor loads fine, as long as I don't try to load data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://URL/scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.PluginManager.load("spellchecker","http://URL/scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/plugin.min.js");
tinymce.PluginManager.load("wordcount","http://URL/scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.min.js");
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea#my_id",   
  theme: "modern",
  plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars ",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "template paste textcolor spellchecker code"
  ],
  relative_urls : true,
  document_base_url : "http://URL/",  
  content_css: "scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/skinslightgray/skin.min.css",
  external_image_list_url : "tinymce_imagelist.js",
  toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | print preview | forecolor backcolor",
  autosave_ask_before_unload: false
});
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("textarea content in here");      // <-- this doesn't work
</script>
<textarea name="Blog_Text" id="my_id" class="editable" cols="60%" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I've tried:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("textarea content in here");
tinyMCE.get("my_id").setContent("textarea content in here");

var ed = tinyMCE.getInstanceById("blog_text");
ed.focus();
ed.setContent("textarea content here");

$('#my_id').html("textarea content here");
```

If I don't try to load the textarea id then the editor loads correctly (without the content).

I've searched for the solution, but NOTHING is working. I really need the solution for this one. I've tried putting the line before the "init" as well as after.

I do wish that examples would be shown in context, just a line doesn't help with a tool as complex and unforgiving as tinymce.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: are you using tinymce4?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. Try with

`tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("textarea content in here");`

Comment: That was a very good suggestion, unfortunately tinymce doesn't like that either, the "editor" doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

**This is one way that I know works:**

I've used the jQuery version of TinyMCE where I initially populate the textarea with existing content like so:

```
var existTxt = "textarea content here";
$('#my_id').html(existTxt);
```

**Then** initialised the TinyMCE editor via a call to a scripted function like so:

```
function updateTxt(my_id) {
        $('#'+ my_id).tinymce({
      ..all of the editor settings..
 });
}
```

The editor initialises, placing the existing textarea content inside the editor with html tags and all.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, using Angular.js, with lots of help from Martin Sansome was to switch to the jQuery plugin version of TinyMCE making sure that I was calling jQuery first on the page and including tinymce.min.js and jquery.tinymce.min.js.

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

In my controller file I set the contents of the textarea to the correct data from the context and then initialize tinyMCE

```
$('#edit_Jobs_Description').html(decodeURIComponent(attrs.jobsdescription));

$('#edit_Jobs_Description').tinymce({
});
```

Now the correct contents shows in the textarea in the edit box on the page.

Finally I had to change the function in the controller that submits the form to use the new content from TinyMCE instead of from the textarea.

```
var jobDescriptionHtml = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks to Martin Sansone.